# Not able to pull selenium image on windows

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm new to docker. When I try to pull the selenium image on windows container I am getting an error:

> image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.

Same image I'm able to download using linux container.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Very likely you are using Windows containers and requested "selenium" image supports only Linux platform.  [Switch to Linux containers](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers) and you will be able to run Linux images.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which means we can't run selenium images on windows containers?

Comment: @Ram that is incorrect assumption. You can run Selenium on windows containers if you use image with windows platform support.